# Why should I use TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME (textPersonName)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have here an `EditText` which I copied from a [dialog example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). The [`textPersonName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME) however doesn't capiltlize like I would expect, which is to put the keyboard into caps before each word in their name. I find myself using [`textCapWords`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS) to achieve this.

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/player_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >
    </EditText>
```

What is the point of `textPersonName` and what might I be loosing switching to `textCapWords`? I thought maybe there was some locale logic behind `textPersonName`, but it doesn't seem to even work in English like I would expect so I'm not so sure.

**Edit**

I have also tried `android:inputType="textCapWords|textAutoComplete|textPersonName"` to see if it would auto complete peoples names, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: when you say you don't expect "this" behavior, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @thepoosh I expect it would put the keyboard into caps before each word in their name, it doesn't even do that, so what does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't lose anything if you stop using it. Currently Android doesn't use this flag at all. At least I checked the source code of the latest Android, and I didn't find any mentioning of this parameter in widgets.

It is possible that this is something that will be used in the future versions of Android, so I would leave it just in case, but you'll do fine without it.